# SQLite3.dll for Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, 64-bit

Within my C# application, I've used the sqlite3 library for 32 bit architecture and all works fine.

To use it, I've copied sqlite3.dll file into my /bin directory and I've created a class called SQLiteWrapper that uses this statement to import sqlite.dll

```
[DllImport("sqlite3.dll", EntryPoint = "........")]
```

Now, I should download this dll file also for 64 bit architecture.
Where I can download it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complied binaries of 64-bit SQLite are bundled with `System.Data.SQLite`  which you can get at  http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: I've downloaded these files: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.66.0/SQLite-1.0.66.0-binaries.zip/download and I see /x64 folder and Into this folder I've these files: System.Data.SQLite.DLL, System.Data.SQLite.exp, System.Data.SQLite.lib. Is it ok?

Answer (score 2):

The binaries proposed in the accepted answer are over 1 year old and so have sqlite 3.6.23.1. If you want the most recent version of system.data.sqlite (with sqlite 3.7.7.1), please get it from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: TrendMicro detected malicious software with this download.