# SQLite sqlite3_column_origin_name function

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-7, 64-bit

I've downloaded the file sqlite.dll precompiled for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0) for my app written in C#.

(I follow this thread: [SQLite3.dll for Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748196/sqlite3-dll-for-windows-7-64-bit))

With my old 32-bit dll the function sqlite3_column_origin_name works correctly, but with latest version for 64-bit, this function give me an error:

```
[DllImport("sqlite3.dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_column_origin_name")]
static extern string sqlite3_column_origin_name(IntPtr stmHandle, int iCol);
```

I use DLL Export Viewer to read exported functions into this dll and this function happears.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: Screenshot of "error" attached
[image]

Comment: What is the error? Hard to say what the cause of the problem is without knowing what the problem is

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't receive any error, now I edit my question with screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found solution.
I've downloaded package from sqlite.org and I've used unmanaged code in combo with precompiled binaries.